# Is it possible to bind events to the recline.js slickgrid view using the "events" feature?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, slickgrid, backbone-views, backbone-events

Using the SlickGrid view from recline.js, I've been trying to bind an click event to a row without success.  It's easy enough to `$('.slick-row').click(function() {...etc})`, but I was hoping to use the backbone-esque view to handle my events.  Nothing seems to fire.  Context seems right.  Is there something obvious I'm overlooking?

My HTML container:

```
<div id="mygrid" style="height: 400px"></div>
```

My JS:

```
  $(function() {    
    var data = [
      {id: 0, date: '2011-01-01', x: 1, y: 2, z: 3, country: 'DE', geo: {lat:52.56, lon:13.40} },
      {id: 1, date: '2011-02-02', x: 2, y: 4, z: 24, country: 'UK', geo: {lat:54.97, lon:-1.60}},
      {id: 2, date: '2011-03-03', x: 3, y: 6, z: 9, country: 'US', geo: {lat:40.00, lon:-75.5}},
      {id: 3, date: '2011-04-04', x: 4, y: 8, z: 6, country: 'UK', geo: {lat:57.27, lon:-6.20}},
      {id: 4, date: '2011-05-04', x: 5, y: 10, z: 15, country: 'UK', geo: {lat:51.58, lon:0}},
      {id: 5, date: '2011-06-02', x: 6, y: 12, z: 18, country: 'DE', geo: {lat:51.04, lon:7.9}}
    ];

    var dataset = new recline.Model.Dataset({
      records: data
    });

    var $el = $('#mygrid');
    var grid = new recline.View.SlickGrid({
      model: dataset,
      el: $el,
      state: { 
        gridOptions: '',
      },
      // Click handler?
      events: {
        'click .slick-row': 'handleClick',
        'click': 'handleClick',
      },
      handleClick: function(e) {
        console.log('row clicked');
      }
    });
    
    grid.visible = true;
    grid.render();
});
```